# sample of the email app for the ios platform

Tags: ios

I want to write a simple email app for ios, that can grab my emails. After investigating it seems that it's not an easy task to do. I found [remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) but it looks very tricky.. Are there any frameworks/libs or open source projects to help me?

Comment: can't use the built-in mail app to "grab your emails"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try mailCore.  Haven't used it myself, but have heard good things [mailCore](http://libmailcore.com)